# MySQL is not running, but PID file exists in Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

sudo mysql.server status
ERROR! MySQL is not running, but PID file exists

Comment: Sounds like your MySQL server crashed. The PID file isn't removed automatically when this happens.

Comment: out of battery, may got improper shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall MYSQL
2. Install MYSQL
3. some time MYSQL not working in mac.

MYSQL will be crashed.